# How to convert joined element collection with JPA 2.1?

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa

I have 3 tables `user`, `user_team` and `team` ...

```
user
--------
id (number)
name (varchar)

team
--------
name (varchar)

user_team
--------
user_id (number) FK -> user.id
team_name (varchar) FK -> team.name
```

and I want load the `User` entity so that teams are converted to correct type.

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    @Column( name = "name" )
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable( name = "user_team", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "user_id" ) )
    @Column( name = "team_name" )
    @Convert( converter = TeamToStringConverter.class )
    private Set<Team> teams;
}

public enum Team { NOTEAM, GEEKS, FREAKS, etc ... }

@Converter
public class TeamToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Team, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn( Team value ) {
        return value == null ? NOTEAM.name() : value.name();
    }
    @Override
    public TEAM convertToEntityAttribute( String value ) {
        return Team.from( value );
    }
}
```

I think the problem is that it uses TeamToStringConverter to convert `user_team.user_id` field instead of `user_team.team_name` field (specified in @Column annotation) and the result is exception:

```
sql.SqlUtils - Attempted to convert SQLException to SQLException. Leaving it alone. [SQLState: null; errorCode: 0]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An error occurred while converting the nvarchar value to JDBC data type INTEGER.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStreamToObject(DDC.java:475)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:2536)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NOTEAM"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the mapping to

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable( name = "user_team", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "user_id" ) )
@Column( name = "team_name" )
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Convert( converter = TeamToStringConverter.class )
private Set<Team> teams;
```

`@CollectionTable` should be used instead of `@JoinTable`, and `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` tells JPA that enum values are stored as `String` in database instead of `Integer` which is the default (index of enum constant).

Note that table `team` doesn't have any meaning to JPA in this setup, because it isn't mapped to anything.

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate version lower that 4.3.9 annotation @Convert does not work for field of collections.

See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9495

For Hibernate lower 4.3.9 use autoApply property:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class TeamToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Team, String> {...}
```

For Hibernate greater 4.3.9 use:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable( name = "user_team", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "user_id" ) )
@Column( name = "team_name" )
@Convert( converter = TeamToStringConverter.class )
private Set<Team> teams;
```