# Converter's type UUID doesn't match with the attribute type Set<UUID>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, converters

I have the following JPA entity attribute with its annotations:

```java
@Convert(converter = UuidConverter.class)
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name ="entity_branch", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="entity_id"))
@Column(name = "branchId")
private Set<UUID> branchId;
```

I get the following compile-time warning:

> Converter's type UUID doesn't match with the attribute type Set

The converter class looks like this:

```java
@Converter
public class UuidConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(UUID attribute) {
        return ofNullable(attribute)
                .map(UUID::toString)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return ofNullable(dbData)
                .map(UUID::fromString)
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Even though I get the warning everything works as expected. How can the warning be fixed without silencing it?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? If yes, which version? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58524431/1225328) seems to say that only 4.3.9+ handles it.

Comment: yes I am using Hibernate 5.4.32.Final. Everything works as expected but I want to get rid of the warning @sp00m